# Rollback Transaction giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollback

I have a stored procedure as

```
Begin
    Begin Transaction [Tran]
    Begin Try
       counter=0 --demo condition

       while(counter<10)
       begin
           condition = condition +1;

           insert something
           delete something

           commit transaction [Tran]
       end -- While End

    end try
    Begin Catch
       rollback transaction [Tran]
    End Catch
End --End for Begin
Go
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I run this, I get the error as :

> The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Comment: You're starting transaction once while committing it within `while` loop on each iteration. And the very first error I guess is that you have no corresponding `begin tran` for `commit`. That's why you are falling into catch block. And getting there another error with same reason. Print `error_message()` first in catch block before attempting to rollback it and check what's there.

Answer (score 1):

You only have begin transaction once, whereas you are committing each time your loop runs.

Comment: Could you let me know, how to do this, When I try to add 1 more begin transaction in the while loop, it goes in the infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read this article about [transactions and error handling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4451/SQL-Server-Transactions-and-Error-Handling).

Try to use this syntax

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

--Your code here

END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    ELSE 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION  
END CATCH
```